# Is there a keyboard shortcut to restart the current console in cmder?

Tags: cmder

It seems like there is with ConEmu https://conemu.github.io/en/KeyboardShortcuts.html "Win+~" but a way to restart the current console in cmder would be great.

Cheers

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Go to Settings - Main - Keys & Macro
Then select "Recreate active console" from the list and set hotkey for it.
This action will show a dialog with three buttons: Restart, Terminate, Cancel. Restart is a default button and you can choose it by just pressing ENTER key.

Answer (score 0):

According to the current help of cmder:

```
 Recreate(<Action>[,<Confirm>[,<AsAdmin>]]), alias "Create"
  - Create new tab or restart existing one
     Action: 0 - create tab, 1 - restart tab, 2 - create window
     Confirm: 1 - show ‘Create new console’ dialog, 0 - don't show
     AsAdmin: 1 - start elevated tab
```

Open Settings - Keys & Macros - Select Macros from dropdown - use one of the unused Macro places (input macro into GUI Macro)

Example:

```
Recreate(1, 0, 1)
```

Restart Tab - do not show confirmation window - start as admin